# Mixed effect model with zero inflated binary (0,1) response where one level of fixed effect has all 0s. Won't converge

Tags: mixed-model, binary-data, zero-inflation

I am trying to use a mixed effect model to determine the relationship between year, season, and depth (my fixed effects) on nutrient outlier presence (dependent variable, 0 or 1). I have two random effects to account for repeated measures of the sampling location and to account for a lack of spatial independence.

Study Design:

I have identified outliers of nutrients in specific spatial locations in the soil. They were measured over 3 years and collected in both the fall and spring for 0cm, 20cm, 40cm, and 60cm depths. The spatial locations are in a 3-dimensional grid and the same locations are repeatedly measured. Each spot at the different sampling times can either be an outlier or not based on if the nutrient flux at the individual locations is greater than the third quartile plus 1.5 x the interquartile range of the entire population of samples in the plot. I am conducting the model on outlier presence, not the overall flux (flux models run fine with the included code). I do not think these data can be considered as counts because there cannot be multiple outliers of a single nutrient at a given sampling (therefore I only have a maximum of 1). My objective  is to identify trends in outlier presence with water year, season, and depth.

Here are my questions:

1. I think my problem is stemming from one level of WATER.YEAR that only has 0s and no 1s. Is this what is causing a large eigenvalue and making the model unidentifiable? Can you explain why this happens?
2. Is it okay to remove the level of WATER.YEAR that is causing this issue? I am running this model with other nutrients (i.e., dependent variables) so I would only want to remove it for this specific nutrient and keep it for the others. This means that not all models would be the same although I am asking the same questions with them.
3. Is there a different type of model for binary data that can account for zero inflation and has random effects? If so, can you provide an example or documentation that may be useful?

Key to the code: `CA.PMO` is the dependent variable coded as 0 and 1 representing when calcium is an outlier (1) or not (0); `WATER.YEAR` is categorical and has 3 levels to represent the sampling year; `SEAS` is categorical and has 2 levels to represent fall and spring; `DEPTH` is continuous with values of 0, 20, 40, and 60; `GRID.L` is random effect for spatial dependence of the locations that were sampled at the same coordinate in the plot but with different depths; `GRID.REP` is a random effect for repeated sampling on the individual location samples were collected.

Code:

```
gm <- glmer(CA.PMO ~ WATER.YEAR + SEAS * DEPTH + (1 | GRID.L) +
                 (1 | GRID.REP), data = fluxdata.1, family = binomial(), 
            control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
                                   optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e4))) 
summary(gm)
```

Error message: 
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?

Dataframe:

```
str(fluxdata.1)
'data.frame':   234 obs. of  61 variables:
 $ WATER.YEAR  : Factor w/ 3 levels "2012","2014",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PLOT        : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GRID        : Factor w/ 16 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ GRID.REP    : Factor w/ 64 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ DEPTH       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SEAS        : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALL","SPR": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ INSTALL.DATE: Factor w/ 6 levels "10.2.13","10.2.15",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ REMOVE.DATE : Factor w/ 6 levels "11.1.11","11.10.15",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ TIME.DAYS   : int  92 92 92 92 92 92 92 92 92 92 ...
 $ TIME        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PRECIP      : num  121 121 121 121 121 ...
 $ NH4         : num  0.1487 2.0046 2.4064 0.0438 0.1264 ...
 $ NO3         : num  0.00642 3.7289 10.05596 0.0005 0.01521 ...
 $ PO4         : num  0.016 1.7436 2.6452 0.0006 0.0006 ...
 $ CA          : num  1.112 7.139 12.352 0.302 0.432 ...
 $ MG          : num  0.1005 1.3361 3.311 0.0249 0.0674 ...
 $ NA.         : num  0.001 0.603 0.832 0.546 0.359 ...
 $ NH4.TIME    : num  0.001617 0.021789 0.026157 0.000476 0.001374 ...
 $ NO3.TIME    : num  6.97e-05 4.05e-02 1.09e-01 5.43e-06 1.65e-04 ...
 $ PO4.TIME    : num  1.74e-04 1.90e-02 2.88e-02 6.52e-06 6.52e-06 ...
 $ CA.TIME     : num  0.01209 0.07759 0.13426 0.00329 0.00469 ...
 $ MG.TIME     : num  0.001092 0.014523 0.035989 0.000271 0.000732 ...
 $ NA.TIME     : num  1.09e-05 6.55e-03 9.05e-03 5.93e-03 3.91e-03 ...
 $ NH4.PMO     : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ NO3.PMO     : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ PO4.PMO     : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ CA.PMO      : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ MG.PMO      : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ NA.PMO      : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ NH4.NMO     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NO3.NMO     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PO4.NMO     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CA.NMO      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ MG.NMO      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NA.NMO      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ NH4.log     : num  0.000702 0.009361 0.011214 0.000207 0.000596 ...
 $ NO3.log     : num  3.03e-05 1.73e-02 4.51e-02 2.36e-06 7.18e-05 ...
 $ PO4.log     : num  7.54e-05 8.15e-03 1.23e-02 2.83e-06 2.83e-06 ...
 $ CA.log      : num  0.00522 0.03246 0.05471 0.00142 0.00203 ...
 $ MG.log      : num  0.000474 0.006262 0.015355 0.000118 0.000318 ...
 $ NA.log      : num  4.72e-06 2.84e-03 3.91e-03 2.57e-03 1.69e-03 ...
 $ NH4.SQRT    : num  0.0402 0.1476 0.1617 0.0218 0.0371 ...
 $ NO3.SQRT    : num  0.00835 0.20132 0.33061 0.00233 0.01286 ...
 $ PO4.SQRT    : num  0.01318 0.13767 0.16956 0.00255 0.00255 ...
 $ CA.SQRT     : num  0.11 0.2786 0.3664 0.0573 0.0685 ...
 $ MG.SQRT     : num  0.0331 0.1205 0.1897 0.0165 0.0271 ...
 $ NA.SQRT     : num  0.0033 0.081 0.0951 0.077 0.0625 ...
 $ NH4.CRT     : num  0.1174 0.2793 0.2968 0.0781 0.1112 ...
 $ NO3.CRT     : num  0.0412 0.3435 0.4781 0.0176 0.0549 ...
 $ PO4.CRT     : num  0.0558 0.2666 0.3064 0.0187 0.0187 ...
 $ CA.CRT      : num  0.23 0.427 0.512 0.149 0.167 ...
 $ MG.CRT      : num  0.103 0.244 0.3302 0.0647 0.0901 ...
 $ NA.CRT      : num  0.0222 0.1871 0.2084 0.181 0.1575 ...
 $ NH4.PEO     : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ NO3.PEO     : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ PO4.PEO     : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ CA.PEO      : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ MG.PEO      : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ NA.PEO      : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ YEAR        : Factor w/ 3 levels "2012","2014",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GRID.L      : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
```

I have tried scaling variables, removing variables, simplifying the model by eliminating a random effect, and making depth categorical. None of these worked.

The model runs perfectly with other nutrients that have a mixture of 0 and 1 for all levels of independent variables. I also was able to get the model to run when I removed the level of WATER.YEAR that has all 0s.

Comment: In order to get useful responses it would be good if you can edit the question to explain your experiment/study design, giving as much details as possible about what all the variables are, and how they were measured. Also include the output of `str(fluxdata.1)`

Comment: Thanks, @RobertLong I have updated my question to include your recommendations.

Comment: Your study seems to hinge on the presence or absence of outliers, yet you haven't said anything about how you determined what an outlier is or how you measure it.

Comment: @RobertLong I have now added that information into the study design section of my question.